# What is the parameter type of handleMachMessage in NSMachPortDelegate?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I tried these code in my Xcode, But just got  `message:4352` in my console.
I wander what is the parameter `(void *)msg` really mean?

```
- (void)launchThread
 {
 _myPort = [[NSMachPort alloc] init];
 if (_myPort)
 {
    [_myPort setDelegate:self];
    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addPort:_myPort forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(LaunchThreadWithPort:)
                             toTarget:self
                           withObject:_myPort];
 }
}

- (void)LaunchThreadWithPort:(id)inData
{
   NSPort *distantPort = (NSPort*)inData;

   [distantPort sendBeforeDate:[NSDate date] msgid:12 components:nil from:nil reserved:123];
}

- (void)handleMachMessage:(void *)msg
{
    NSLog(@"message:%d", *(int *)msg);
}
```

Comment: `void*` is a pointer to some unknown data type.

Comment: It's a *Mach message*, which starts with `msg_header_t`.  Your question seems strange, if you aren't already sending Mach messages.

Comment: I'm not sure if it is a correct way to send message by `[distantPort sendBeforeDate:[NSDate date] msgid:12 components:nil from:nil reserved:123];`, Is there any way to get the information of msgid by `handleMachMessage `?

Comment: I have been able to get the msgid from the msg_header_t , but is "components" a payload?  If so, how do we get it?  I didn't see anything in msg_header_t that even remotely looks like "components"..